# Hw can I get Url params (id for example) in request made by php artisan make:request

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a Request made by php artisan make:request wherein rules I can add a param, for instance I have the following validator in the controller:

```
      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:{{number}}',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Where number is from url parameter
How can I get this url parameter in my Request class?

Here is my Request class:

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Blog\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class SaveBlogCategoriesRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        dd($request->param);
        return [
            'lang' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => "required|unique:blog_categories_id,slug,", // here I want to add id from param
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        $data = [
                'status' => false,
                'validator' => true,
                'msg' => [
                    'e' => $validator->messages(),
                    'type' => 'error'
                ],
        ];

        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($data));
    }
}
```

Comment: `$request->param;` if your param name is id so simply like `$request->id;`

Comment: I don't have $request in my Request class

Comment: Use `request()` instead of `$request`

Comment: Use $validated = $request->validated();

Comment: @Dmitry But ... "_I don't have $request in my Request class_"

Comment: use Request on the top and in rules method simply call request as you do in controller `rules(Request $request)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the request class, you dont need to instantiate the validator

```php
class ModelCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        //if you need the input, you can access it via $this->request;
        $param = $this->request->get('param');
        //or you can also access it directly (yeah I know it not intuitive)
        $param = $this->param
        return [
            'lang' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => "required|unique:blog_categories_id,slug,".$param,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I want to get value of key from Route::get('controllerMethod/{key}', $controller . 'controllerMethod') in my request class; Is it possible?

Comment: @Marius same, use `$this->key`

Answer (score 0):

Use `dd($this)`  to get the request object in request class